# What are options scanf vs gets vs fgets?

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets, format-specifiers

I heve a following code

```
while ( a != 5)
 scanf("%s", buffer);
```

This works well but takes no space in between the mentioned words or in other words, scanf terminates if we use spaces to scan

If I use this

```
while( a != 5)
 scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
```

It works only for once which is bad

I never use `gets()` because I know how much nasty it is..

My last option is this

```
while( a != 5)
  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

So my questions are

1. Why the second command is not working inside the loop?
2. What are the other options I have to scan a string with spaces?

Comment: What's `a`? where does it change? What's it's initial value? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd go with the third option and then trim the newline as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109)

Comment: In all 3 cases, checking the return value of `scanf()/fgets()` is necessary before using `buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%[^\n]"` will attempt to scan everything until a newline. The next character in the input would be the `\n` so you should skip over it to get to the next line.

Try: `"%[^\n]%*c"`, the `%*c` will discard the next character, which is the newline char.

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` has issues.  Try entering only a newline - `buffer` is not altered, left as is - maybe uninitialized.  Same problem with `"%[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: Ok? but the assumption is that there is text to process, so irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why the second command is not working inside the loop*

Becuase, for the first time what you *scan* until `\n`, the `\n` is remaining in the input buffer. You need to *eat up* (or, in other word, discard)  the stored newline from the buffer. You can make use of `while (getchar()!=`\n`);` to get that job done.

> *What are the other options I have to scan a string with spaces?*

Well, you're almost there. You need to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Using this, you can

1. Be safe from buffer overrun (Overcome limitation of `gets()`)
2. Input strings with *spaces* (Overcome limitation of `%s`)

However, please keep in mind, `fgets()` reads and stores the trailing newline, so you may want to get rid of it and you have to do that yourself, manually.

Comment: sorry bro my mistake, the third function is not fscanf, its fgets only..a simple typo...

Comment: `scanf()` + `%s` also has the same issue as #1.